# How can I add a field dynamically to a Java class using Groovy?

Tags: ruby, groovy, metaprogramming, language-features

In Ruby I can add instance variables to a class by opening it, and doing something like this :

```
class Whatever
   def add_x
     @x = 20
   end
end
```

and this would add me an instance variable by the name of x. How can I do the same thing in Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Groovy's metaclass:

```
class Foo { String bar }
f = new Foo(bar:"one")
f.metaClass.spam = "two"
f.spam == "two" // returns true
f.spam = "eggs" // Change property value
f.spam == "eggs" //returns true
```

Comment: NOTE: This only adds the variables to a particular instance of a class.